# Differences between use of os.path.join and os.sep concatenation

Tags: python, string, path, operating-system

I am trying to figure out if it is better to use:

```
os.path.join(str1, str2)
```

or:

```
str1 + os.sep + str2
```

Profiling with `timeit` I found that, as expected, concatenation is faster:

```
%timeit 'playground' + os.sep + 'Text'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 139 ns per loop

%timeit os.path.join('playground', 'Text')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 830 ns per loop
```

So my question is, since concatenation is also shorter, is there a reason to use `os.path.join(()`?

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's right there in the documentation:

> `os.path.join(path1[, path2[, ...]])`
>
> Join one or more path components **intelligently**. If any component is an absolute path, all previous components (on Windows, including the previous drive letter, if there was one) are thrown away, and joining continues. The return value is the concatenation of `path1`, and optionally `path2`, etc., with exactly one directory separator (`os.sep`) following each non-empty part except the last. (This means that an empty last part will result in a path that ends with a separator.) Note that on Windows, since there is a current directory for each drive, `os.path.join("c:", "foo")` represents a path relative to the current directory on drive `C:` (`c:foo`), not `c:\foo`.

`os.path.join` does much more:

```
>>> os.path.join("/home/", "/home/foo")
'/home/foo'
>>> "/home/" + os.sep + "/home/foo"
'/home///home/foo'
```

You will never have a situation where `os.path.join` is the bottleneck of your program, so use it, it's much more readable too.

Comment: I would not recommend using it, when you know, you don't need it. The result of `os.path.join` is less predictable, and introducing overhead for absolutely nothing is not "premature optimization" but just bad coding style. It is not a bottleneck but the cumulation of such decisions is, what makes modern computers slow. If, for example, you have a path you got from `os.path.realpath` and a filename of which you know that it contains no slashes, `os.sep.join` is the better choice, as it is in most situations.

Answer (score 7):

`os.path.join` takes multiple arguments:

```
import os
os.path.join('a', 'b', 'c')
```

This will become rather long with concatenation for many path parts.